# How much can you change a question to keep it current

Tags: discussion

**TL;DR - can a remove a specific restriction to compatible OS if the requirement is extremely outdated in an effort to keep the question and answers up to date and attract new answers to help future visitors.**

I asked [Is there software to automatically backup photos from Android device without going through a web service?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/is-there-software-to-automatically-backup-photos-from-android-device-without-goi) over 7 years ago.  One of my criteria was "The Android App would ideally be compatible with Android 4.0, but most of the devices are using Android 4.3", which was brand new at the time, but is decidedly dated in 2021.

Given people seem to still be looking at that question (I got a "famous question" badge for it recently), would it be inappropriate to remove the restriction to the specific android version so more recent/modern tools could become answers?

I know the core idea is to not invalidate existing answers, but I don't think it would invalidate any of the answers since none specifically mention the old version requirement

Comment: Great you take care even for your old questions! While edits could be made quite clear (e.g. using `<s>` to strike-through the original and adding your updates), and indeed wouldn't invalidate any of the answers, I don't think it's really needed in this case. You could of course indicate an "or newer" for Android and Windows Server if you're looking for new solutions. <= just my personal opinion, hence a comment.